# Sometimes module not started

Tags: c++, linux, system, strace

Need help in next investigation :

On one bad-Linux-machine *sometimes* one of my module not started. In other ok-Linux-machine ( the same OS, the same module ) - my module start always. Architecture is next : one module ( mymain ) load patch of another modules and start it with call system() function.

Code :

```
int ret = system(mypatch);
```

where mypatch - name of my module, for example "usr/local/test/module1".
Value ret always = 0;

Using **strace** is very rare : in bad-Linux-machine strace not working properly - calling of my module is not present in trace-file, other side - in ok-Linux-machine - I see all information :

```
execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/usr/local/test/module1 &"],....)
```

*OS : Red Hat Entterprise Linux Server release 5.3 ( Tikanga )*

strace use : *strace -s 512 -o fail -f -v -ff ./mymain*

**Question** : any idea ?

Comment: Add full output of `strace` and types and full paths of all files you are talking about (use `file(1)`).

Comment: Question is closed. 

Error in code in my start method, where I find 'running or no' another instance of this module. And because "ps x grep mymodule" return two strings, I thinks - "hmmm, this is second copy of module", and see in code - return 1 :)